# avr-ld: avr:51 architecture of input file `main.o' is incompatible with avr output

Tags: c, linker, avr, atmega, avr-gcc

I tried to use [**this Code/Guide**](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/tree/master/sys/avr/atmega328) on an `ATmega1284p`.

The problem that I encounter is that the linker does not work, and I get following error message after executing (code builds well for `ATmega88`):

```
avr-ld  -o main.elf main.o  -g

avr-ld: avr:51 architecture of input file `main.o' is incompatible with avr output
```

---

**For information**

```
avr-gcc -v    
Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=avr-gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
    Target: avr
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/usr/lib --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --bindir=/usr/bin --libexecdir=/usr/lib --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --enable-long-long --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --disable-libssp --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=avr
    Thread model: single
```

---

**Complete build instructions**

```
avr-gcc -std=c99 -g -Os -mmcu=atmega1284p -DF_CPU=8000000 -I. -DUART_BAUDRATE=57600 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wextra -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,-gc-sections -o main.o -o main.o *.c 
avr-ld  -o main.elf main.o  -g
avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex main.o main.hex
avr-size -C --mcu=atmega1284p main.elf
```

---

**avr-objdump output of main.o**

```
avr-objdump -f main.o

main.o:     Dateiformat elf32-avr
Architektur: avr:51, Flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
Startadresse 0x00000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround to force `avr-ld` to use an linkerscript.

### Workaround

If avr-ld is giving the error:

`avr-ld: avr:51 architecture of input file 'main.o' is incompatible with avr output`

You must add the desired architecture with the option `-m`, for example:

```
avr-ld  -o main.elf main.o  -g -mavr51
```

If this does not work you get following error:

```
avr-ld: cannot open linker script file ldscripts/avr51.xn: No such file or directory
```

You must force using the right linkerscript with the `-T` option:

```
avr-ld  -o main.elf main.o  -g -mavr51 -T /usr/lib/avr/ldscripts/avr51.xn
```

And the linker should work.